# How to implement custom route in ASP.NET MVC containing dot?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

Instead of the conventional MVC route of

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

I need my system to handle requests like this

```
{controller}/{action}.{id}
```

e.g.
http://localhost:50691/epws/openWebViewer.x551

I have no control over the system calling me

I modified my routeconfig as such

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}.{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

with the following controller

```
public class epwsController : Controller
    {    
        public ActionResult openWebViewer(string id)
        {
            return View(id);
        }

    }
```

but the URL above just returns a 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like below, remove action parameter from url with route attributes. Then extend id parameter, so string "openWebViewer.x551" gets inside of the action as a whole and do some inner routing inside controller. Finally add web.config setting to add trailing slash to URL so it does not get handled by static file handler

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication8.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("epws")]
    public class EpwsController : Controller
    {
        [Route("{id}")]
        public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {
            var parameters = id.Split('.');

            switch (parameters[0])
            {
                case "openWebViewer":
                    return openWebViewer(parameters[1]);
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public ActionResult openWebViewer(string id)
        {
            return View(id);
        }
    }
}
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Add trailing slash for some URLs" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*(\.).+[^\/])$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

I believe static files will be broken with this web.config, but you could adjust regex to match only specific parameter names, e.g. openWebViewer